# ExecutorService throws NullPointerException during JBoss startup

Tags: java, jboss, executorservice

I want to use the ManagedScheduledExecutorService API from Java EE 7 for dynamic executing background tasks in my JSF Java EE Web application.

In the moment, i'm stuck at the point, when to put the background tasks into the ManagedScheduledExecutorService.

I already tried 3 different solutions, all execute at the time of war deployment and not at the time of JBoss finished starting up. Problem is, that the ManagedScheduledExecutorService is probably not available during webapplication deployment and I only receive a NullPointerException.

Do you have an idea, how to schedule my background task after jboss finished starting up not after application deployment.

---

Here my 3 solutions I tried - all ending up executing before JBoss finished starting.

**First solution:**

Class annotated with @Singleton and @Startup
and 2 methods with @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy

**Second solution:**

Class implementing ServletContextListener and annotated with @WebListener
and 2 methods contextDestroyed and contextInitialized from the interface

**Third solution:**

Class with 2 methods public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object o) and public void destroy( @Observes @Destroyed( ApplicationScoped.class ) Object o )

---

Code, that is used for initialize the background tasks to the ExecutorService:

```
@Resource
private ManagedScheduledExecutorService executorService;
private List<ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledTasks;

public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object o) {

    this.scheduledTasks = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ScheduledFuture<?>>());

    ScheduledFuture<Boolean> task = executorService.schedule(() -> {
        try {
            //Do work
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log error
            return false;
        }
    }, new Trigger() {
        @Override
        public Date getNextRunTime(LastExecution le, Date date) {
            return getNextDate(10);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean skipRun(LastExecution le, Date date) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    scheduledTasks.add(task);
}
```

Comment: can you share the code please. at least releated part

Comment: Code for solution 3 added. 10 seconds after application deployment but JBoss is not finished, the NullPointerException in the Java provided class ManagedScheduledExecutorService occurs.

Comment: can you share the exception too please.

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?